# Not able to create Azure Container Instance with CLI using private image

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-registry, azure-container-instances

I can't deploy pod using private image (ACR) using CLI and yaml file.

Deploying from registry directly using either az container or kubectl run does work however.

Pod status:

```
  "containers": [
    {

            "count": 3,
            "firstTimestamp": "2017-08-26T07:31:36+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2017-08-26T07:32:20+00:00",
            "message": "Failed: Failed to pull image \"ucont01.azurecr.io/unreal-deb\": rpc error: code 2 desc Error: im age unreal-deb:latest not found",
            "type": "Warning"
          },
        ],
      },
```

Yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  generateName: "game-"
  namespace: default
spec:
  nodeName: aci-connector
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
    - name: unreal-dev-server
      image: ucont01.azurecr.io/unreal-deb
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
      - containerPort: 7777
        protocol: UDP
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: registrykey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the aci-connector-k8s doesn't currently support images from private repositories. There is an issue open to add support but it's not currently implemented.

https://github.com/Azure/aci-connector-k8s/issues/35

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, could you please check your `repositories` via Azure portal, like this:

[image]

Use your YAML, it work for me:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  generateName: "game-"
  namespace: default
spec:
  nodeName: k8s-agent-379980cb-0
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
    - name: unreal-dev-server
      image: jasontest.azurecr.io/samples/nginx
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
      - containerPort: 7777
        protocol: TCP
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: secret1
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my `secret`:

```
jason@k8s-master-379980CB-0:~$ kubectl get secret
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
default-token-865dj   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         1h
secret1               kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         47m
```

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials (corresponding to registrykey) are incorrect, you may get 'image not found' error, though the image exists. you may want to verify the registrykey credentials again..

Comment: I added another secret point to the same registry and it still doesn't work. I can run images from the same registry using kubectl run --image=. I'm fairly positive that credentials are ok then.